# Should I have multiple swf files on different webpages?

Tags: flash, flash-cs4

I'm writing a small game app in Flash, and I'm wondering what the benefits of having one giant SWF loading everything vs multiple webpages and multiple SWF's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine that having multiple SWFs/pages would annoy the users and possibly cause more overhead to manage, ie: what happens when the user presses the back button? etc etc